# How to write on a x,y-position in a terminal in python (text based)

Tags: python

I want to write characters on a defined position (x,y) in a terminal in python (text based).

Suppose, I have a terminal with size 25x80 and want to write a character on position (2,20).
Can I do this in Python.

Now, I use a 25x80 array, and write into this array. To display on the screen, I clear the screen and write the entire contents of this array to the screen, but this is not efficient...

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: you're looking for the [python curses module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/curses.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
x = int(input('Enter value of x : '))
y = int(input('Enter value of y : '))
ch = input('Enter the Character : ')

print('\n' * y  + ' ' * x  + ch)
print('\n\n\n\n') #just for sparing some lines after the output
```

If you want to keep rest of the screen blank and just output one character, this is a good way.

All I did was entered `\n` (newline) character as long as i reached the right y cords.

After that i entered space as long as i reached x cords.

Comment: Suppose I want to bounce a ball against the borders, can't I just replace the previous position with a space and the current with my "ball"-character?

Comment: I don't think so. String in python is immutable. If I was to reproduce a bouncing ball I would clear the screen after every iteration, and recalculate the values of x and y. And execute the statement `print('\n' * y  + ' ' * x  + ch)` .

Comment: Then making a 2D list is a better way (in my opinion). You can address a 2D list bij its row,col (i.e. y,x) coordinates.
Afterwards, you cat loop through the list and write it to the screen, after a screen clear.
I was wondering if you can write *directly* to the screen for a certian coordinate, without using a string or 2D-list.

Comment: Yeah there are graphics libraries for python too. You can search online for one of them. They are easy to start with. If you making some simple animation you can try PyGame too. Or for just simple plots Matplotlib.

Comment: I still think printing a string after clear screen continuously is still more efficient than printing a 2D list after cllear screen. continuously.